# Where should I place additional classes in my MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class-library, s#arp-architecture, app-code

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which is using Linq to SQL classes placed in the Model folder.

I want to create some extra classes that I would normally place in my BLL but I'm not sure how to work this with MVC.

With WebForms I would have my DAL as a Class Library. 
My BLL as a class library that referenced my BLL.
My Web Site that referenced both the DAL and BLL.

The problem I am facing is, if I create a class library, this will need to reference my MVC Application because it will need to use the types contained in my Model.

If I then add (or try to add) a reference to my class library, I will get a circular dependency.

In Web Forms. My other option would be to place the classes in the App_Code.
Is there an equivalent of App_Code in a MVC application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move *all* your models to the class library, can't you? Neither MVC or VS mind. This would remove the dependency of the Models library on the Web app.

Answer (score 2):

You can place that in the model folder. As all the business related classed are place into that folder

For better practice see the [scottgu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu) the [nerddinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) examples. He has created the respiratory classes in nerdinner application.

Comment: thanks for the scottgu tip.
"You can place that in the model class" Did you mean Model folder?

Answer (score 1):

I agree in terms of the **Model** folder. You can organize it to your heart's content (BLL, DAL, etc.).

I personally would avoid doing a separate assembly unless you have a compelling reason to. Being the kind of developer that tends to over-complicate problems if I'm not careful, I try to follow the KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid) practices as much as possible, which tends to keep me out of a certain amount of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at S#arp Architecture. You can either use the template they provide or use it as a reference to help you make decisions.

http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/